Equivalent statement to Hall's theorem
I am trying to prove that a bipartite graph $G$ on $(X, Y)$, contains a matching perfect to $X$ if and only if
$$
|X\setminus N(T)| \leq |Y\setminus T| \; \; \forall \; T \subseteq Y
$$
Forward direction is immediate from Hall's theorem. I am trying to prove the converse using Hall's theorem as well, but just can't seem to get it right. I always end up in a situation that relies on that any subset $S \subseteq X$ can be expressed as $X \setminus N(T)$ for some appropriate $T \subseteq Y$. However, I doubt this is possible..
Any help would be very much appreciated:)

@koifish it does!
